# Will git rebase in this scenario return the same hash?

Tags: git

```
A -- B -- C <-- master
       \
        D -- E <-- your-cool-branch
```

I've realized there are some typo in my source code comments in commit D. I would still like to submit the pull request as two commits D' and E', where D' is the fixed version of D, and E' is the same exact diff as E.

If I rebase do to make this happen will the E' commit hash be the same E? Why or why not?

I have tried replicating this but I must not be rebasing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any rebase would, be definition, change E' SHA1 commit, since the parent won't be the same: it will be D' whose new parent after rebase (C) will have changed from B before.
Plus D itself is modified by your fix.

So after a `git rebase master`:

```
A -- B -- C <-- master
           \
            D' -- E' <-- your-cool-branch
```

See "[The anatomy of a Git commit](https://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html)" from **[Christoph Burgdorf](https://twitter.com/cburgdorf)**: a commit ID would include:

```
sha1(
    commit message  => "second commit"
    committer        => Christoph Burgdorf <christoph.burgdorf@gmail.com>
    commit date     => Sat Nov 8 11:13:49 2014 +0100
    author          => Christoph Burgdorf <christoph.burgdorf@gmail.com>
    author date     => Sat Nov 8 11:13:49 2014 +0100
    tree            => 9c435a86e664be00db0d973e981425e4a3ef3f8d
    parents         => [0d973e9c4353ef3f8ddb98a86e664be001425e4a]
)
```

Or: [Git Object model](http://shafiul.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html)

[image: http://shafiul.github.io/gitbook/assets/images/figure/object-commit.png]